# Macbook Pro 14" M1 logs in with Touch ID but not with password

Tags: macbook-pro, password, monterey, apple-silicon, touch-id

For some reason I can't login to my Mac with a typed password, *only* with Touch ID.

I have checked if I was entering correctly, if caps lock was activated and have also changed the password, but I simply can't log in with any typed password.

The reason I know why I'm not typing it incorrectly is that *after logging in with touch ID I go to "Settings" and unlock it using the same password with success.* Even when I change my password, the new one can also unlock the settings app, but can't unlock my Mac.

Although it isn't stopping me from doing anything right now I'm a bit worried that if for some reason my Touch ID stops working for I might lose access to my laptop.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: In System Prefs > Users & Groups > Login Options click `Show input menu in login window`. The only configuration thing I can think of is that the Mac is looking for a keyboard in another language localization, and when you login next time, see if it is set to something other than what you expect. If so, see if you can switch back to your normal keyboard. Also, have you tested this with another keyboard to see if the same problem exists?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Not sure what it was, afeterall. Apparently after rebooting everything went bac to normal.

Answer (score 0):

So... I'm still not sure about what it was, but I guess it was related to my session cache or something.

It has been quiet a while since I last restarted my Mac (maybe a couple weeks) and I haven't actually changed my password since first setting it up after I bought it about a month ago. But after restarting it I was able to logging in with a typed password once again.

Being kind of used to linux (Debian distros) I should've thought about it before, but since I have never changed the password before, simply didn't think about it.

Comment: Sometimes a simple restart fixes a lot of odd problems. Although there's a lot of ribbing by Unix users towards macOS users about the need to restart the OS, it does help a large number of problems.